# python-sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table named Province with column name id, District and Municipality. So, If I select any  District values , then its respective municipality value should be displayed. How do I do it?

[image]

If I select District values named Kapilvastu, then its respective Municipality values named Kapilvastu should come as an output.

Answer (score 1):

I think an SQL statement like this should work!

```
SELECT Municipality FROM Province WHERE District = 'District Name'
```